# Issue configuring Apache virtualHost with modwsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, python, mod-wsgi

Hello i have a problem configuring apache with Virtualhosts and ModWSGI, see i want to run a Python Script when i access to the domain, but it keeps showing me the content of my folder instead executing the script.

Here is the site-enabled configuration:

```
#
```

## *.karinapp.com (/etc/httpd/sites-available/karinapp.com)

#

        ServerAdmin info@websergroup.com
        ServerName  karinapp.com
        ServerAlias *.karinapp.com

```
    #Indexes + Directory Root
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/karinapp.com/
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/karinapp.com/Suite">
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
    #LOG FILES
    ErrorLog  /var/www/vhosts/karinapp.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/karinapp.com/logs/access.log combined
```

This is the code of the .htaccess that is on the Suite folder

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/badrequest.html

ErrorDocument 401 /errors/authreqd.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbid.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/serverr.html
allow from all
DirectoryIndex /Suite/Gate.py
```

Comment: Is the module mod_wsgi loaded anywhere in the configuration?

Comment: Yes, is loaded on the conf on the /etc/httpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check few things .. 
In your httpd.conf `LoadModule` should be enabled ti execute your cgi files.(wsgi is nothing but a cgi file only, a script)

Change your Directory Options

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/karinapp.com/Suite">
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
AllowOverride All
Options +ExecCGI FollowSymLinks +Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all</Directory>
```

Becuse it executes it in left to right manner ,its like a or statement .
Hope this helps..